# Why does updating a form cause onFormSubmit trigger to run?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

My code here:

```
   function script1(){
  //What is the form and data item ID?
  var form = FormApp.openById("Form ID");
  var namesList = form.getItemById("Item ID").asListItem();


//What sheet is used to update the form?
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("Update");

  // Grab the values in the sixth column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row
  var namesValues = names.getRange(2, 6, names.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();

  var departmentNames = [];

  // Convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < namesValues.length; i++)   
    if(namesValues[i][0] != "")
      departmentNames[i] = namesValues[i][0];

  // Populate the drop-down
  namesList.setChoiceValues(departmentNames);
 
}
```

appears to triggers the form to submit causing problems.  I have an onFormSubmit trigger set up to copy the data to a database and then delete the row.  Unfortunately, the headers keep getting copied to the database since the form does not actually send any data and the only row with data is the headers.  How can I update the form without the form submitting?  Screenshot example is included below.

[[image: Screenshot sample...1]

I hope I was able to make myself clear.  Thank you for any help.

**Modified Screenshot**
[image: Modified Screenshot]

Here is a screenshot of the trigger and its executions.
[image: Triggers]

Comment: Hi. 1) this script does NOT trigger the form to submit. Look at the "Executions" screen to find what functions are being executed BUT this function is NOT the cause. 2) the duplicate is on your database since the image above is NOT the Form Responses sheet (Column A is "Time" vs "Timestamp").

Comment: Please show the triggers that are set for your project as well the execution logs correspoding to the firing of the onFormSubmit triggers.

Comment: Sorry.  The original image above is a sample spreadsheet I quickly typed up to protect sensitive information.  It is not the actual spreadsheet.  The modified image above, @Tedinoz, is more like what I am getting, which exactly corresponds to the fields in the Form Responses.

Comment: The time-based triggers have all executed successfully, and the Edit History in the cells indicate that the data is being input when these triggers are executed.  That is why it appeared that updating the form with this script was causing the form to submit and the data that was being transferred was the headers from the Form Response spreadsheet.  However, the onFormSubmit trigger execution times do not correspond.

Comment: OK-`script1` does NOT update the FormResponses sheet, the `onFormSubmit` trigger execution times do not correspond and, I am guessing, the duplication is on the "database" not the FormResponses Sheet. Is this question -[Moving apps script from Spreadsheet to Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75232840/1330560) - related/helpful? I'm also intrigued about why the `onFormSubmit` trigger didn't show on the "Executions" screen; did you "filter" the output to show only "time-driven". Would you please add for `onFormSubmit` script, and the related "Executions" screen, to the question.

Comment: Just BTW, I NEVER modify/delete entries on the "FormResponses" sheet. It is sacrosanct. If If you want/need to make a new sheet to add additional fields, etc, then making a copy (as you are doing) is the way to go.